# While using chunked requests on raspberry pi getting warning 'Connection pool is full'

Tags: python, linux, python-requests, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3

I am using Nuance for speech recognition and I'm doing it with chunk request
like this:

```
import Audio
import logging
import json
import requests

nuance_creds = 'credentials.json'


def listen():
    source = Audio.Microphone(sample_rate=16000, chunk_size=1024)
    source.open_stream()

    while True:
        try:
            yield source.read()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break


logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)


with open(nuance_creds, 'r') as raw_credentials:  # reads the credentials for nuance api
    credentials = json.loads(raw_credentials.read())

appId = credentials['appId']
appKey = credentials['appKey']
asrUrl = credentials['asrUrl']
asrEndpoint = credentials['asrEndpoint']
requestor_Id = 'fc2jvf7p'

base_url = '%s%s?appId=%s&appKey=%s&id=%s'

base_url = base_url % (asrUrl, asrEndpoint, appId, appKey, requestor_Id)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav;bit=16;codec=pcm;rate=16000',
    'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'Accept': 'text/plain',
    'Accept-Topic': 'Dictation'
}

req = listen()

response = requests.post(url=base_url, data=req, headers=headers, timeout=10,
                         stream=True)

print 'You said: {}'.format(response.text)
```

In Audio class I am using alsaaudio to read buffer from the microphone,
so read function returns raw audio.
this script runs fine on regular desktop computer running ubuntu
the problem starts when using raspberry pi(jessie lite), at the end of the post I am getting some warning like this

> INFO:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): dictation.nuancemobility.net
>
> WARNING:Connection pool is full, discarding connection:
>   dictation.nuancemobility.net
>
> You said: Hello

I tried using requests session to increase the number of pool connections but it seems it doing just nothing, even if I give 100 connections its not solving the problem, but on desktop computer it seems that even one connection is enough.
The script above is just for debugging, so in my project I'm already using it. but still this warning doesn't suppose to happen, so I really want to get rid of it.

with extended request:

```
session = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(
                pool_connections=100, pool_maxsize=100)

session.mount('https://', adapter)

session.post(url=base_url, data=req, headers=headers, timeout=10,
                         stream=True)
```

Comment: You need to provide an updated code where you extend number of connections. Most likely you did something wrong there. It is the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131873/python-requests-warning-urllib3-connectionpoolconnection-pool-is-full

Comment: I edited the post, I think this is not the problem I tried with 'http://' also and its not working. what is strange is that this problem only appears on the raspberry pi and not on desktop computer, maybe the problem is in the OS?