# Docker: Filesystem is not responding

Tags: docker

I have to run 43 containers on the local machine.

Each startup I have warnings

```
WARNING: Connection pool is full, discarding connection: localhost
```

Warning don't block my work

But sometimes at containers startup, I got multiple errors below

```
Filesystem is not responding
Filesystem mounted at /var/lib/docker/overlay/{hash}/merged is not responding
```

A lot of them pushed as notifications in my manjaro KDE
These errors block my work, containers not working. Only reboot helps me.

I will provide any additional information you need

Filesystem is ext4
Storage driver: overlay2

```
docker system df 
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              16                  10                  3.82GB              1.198GB (31%)
Containers          43                  43                  1.138MB             0B (0%)
Local Volumes       20                  10                  1.947GB             955.4MB (49%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

```
sudo docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
3e046a2f4038        bridge              bridge              local
8aadcba2673b        dev_default         bridge              local
0f58cf29be50        host                host                local
dace3c787c02        none                null                local
```

```
sudo docker network inspect dev_default
[
    {
        "Name": "dev_default",
        "Id": "8aadcba2673b48477a439252f9528493511d63d017acbe7981893e9abc8ef1ce",
        "Created": "2020-02-14T13:40:06.643398755+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "016e0d8ec547831d3cb4ed971ccc9d4dd7c21d7bbd17d2295d9b6c2f37250ce1": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800014_1",
                "EndpointID": "4d665c749b325820aac33d415baa8467e49b549c928d730b0fd16a01423f94c9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.10/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "060a555c3a813188d49c06d22170eab6555b4acf6f532bf3c7dd7ea82f01b5fb": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800038_1",
                "EndpointID": "85a43daca97c55f2ea2c83401468ba64315997f8c817d22fc81a2b54283236dc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:10",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.16/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "06aba1b6a003e42388fd4d4feaa66ab8f2fbab853bf32bf74ef50050cba30ae6": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800015_1",
                "EndpointID": "2541a4e7d05c88ea2a6bccc3280b5eac8437646ed07fa13d6bd00a65aae0331d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:12",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.18/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "085d84226f8aa471ccbf784f7c34be362371d481d7a157ec87538c631c85868a": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400017_1",
                "EndpointID": "0bef199879d04a55e0916d943cef1e883cf0032a32fc7c6ff6cc71bc2eb5d397",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:15",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.21/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "09fbe0b08f81f1b30a056bcddbf02bafe50f5367447eea52393d6f85fe9e6e95": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400019_1",
                "EndpointID": "0ab5142fa4f578b23600e0a1b00433009368a82efad15cb7b29273095b4ddb81",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:20",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.32/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "160f645c05d1a7ca3c7189a24cbd1aa598ae64a0eced259580e5475544556e99": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800016_1",
                "EndpointID": "3b376a61b5bd383b4ac92ad959bce1d51fa8f189bb8dc54c086ad0e7ad0c0ee3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "18d5f68d2f5d5fc2d39ecad9d16bdb75af91d74626ac77c559fd508c2e75e1e8": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400031_1",
                "EndpointID": "771bb76578e24aba74f4780b5e3f02d7aa03bd1e6c6b0311ca8a4e66fcd00ea3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:16",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.22/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "23c427c2b75f27b79f2fe83eb9d361d506786fc2f702d5b854d443d14683b0da": {
                "Name": "dev_tdiRelay_1",
                "EndpointID": "00331149f91abef709e1eb494a937cbe534ef4bfa5da137edb648e748ff800e0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:2b",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.43/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "272c718eaa25a45952eceb860d875418b6ba6a68db026733052e67b7efa3ab8d": {
                "Name": "dev_tdiParser_1",
                "EndpointID": "02fecfde12e183c6ece57f1ab96b858fb4e3b0f1977a47a00f61ce9ece7960fa",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:2c",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.44/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "29e9a0e3fa9eff5185fc6dda092f4358140c4ca852d97f31c31c77055b1ffe60": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400013_1",
                "EndpointID": "4a501dcf83ba64273512a5381c562abbdc5dba0d0b6d01fe68a03499674e2f15",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:0f",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.15/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2cb4e8011fa4c338803f546dfb9181936030cae6d3d4eddddd7af0a04137f2b6": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800010_1",
                "EndpointID": "0dc1d7639077e18c511b75638f9995e5a052914da6e14bca174fd6a8217ca2d4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:17",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.23/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "408a7b4f1f1c92be7022f514775ebc93fd6359237b74704da73ee51b158cbfe2": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800031_1",
                "EndpointID": "380cfac2b1200c530d5c665b5290d8930448ed39c56710d29fe191af5e748d7d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:0d",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.13/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "43bda6ed5698b59d90fa1479547efa2c4bbcec187b03d4990632217bbb4cec9c": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800018_1",
                "EndpointID": "c77dac271dedc5d05968a17fbf665358ba214d03a67dca082c37668410d0f1a2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:18",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.24/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "44a1e95f87f1eac91bfc06a16a32b8b478df871af9b9d1d9bf095e6f2b075e5a": {
                "Name": "dev_maintempdb_1",
                "EndpointID": "4021ea4e27729adeaa81b7d0bd6f7c67be17734c4d67b14d660880f7c0531f37",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "554f1a422ece3eb0558a747ef6d63dba6b0e9d019c438d118ded9ff76ef176df": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400040_1",
                "EndpointID": "f2a3bb793ab5be3e7c1276d38b3ad3a922ea0a901fa990e356a722875aa1556a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:14",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.20/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5932a2cb3803e390ce98ef823610e6f3ca12213e52b9812c2d4b5519b473e709": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800023_1",
                "EndpointID": "81b45bb2b1832a83dab9dfc803e44a724ffd5a6a1bc6e11fc4577b6489b090ed",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "596314ba1bebbb5938735e7559a2cad8a3927a0b222c9a42f6a2abab2184779e": {
                "Name": "dev_mainq_1",
                "EndpointID": "9bc8505918c5bef6132172e90c5b50e4801a213e5fb7f18c54f8a841e0deee26",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:22",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.34/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "61dea1acffa8eb3508bbf4c90d17fc01b32c7da578682555343d053ca65add04": {
                "Name": "dev_outerdb_1",
                "EndpointID": "4613444ab9c6e33dc6eb35ff0d5400a8d34b1ceeb30d8e1bb2f607ec9fb953db",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:23",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.35/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "666aa5be6401cd4ac2fe34a74789e0a5e210c46fc43a569448f6f51cc255fa61": {
                "Name": "dev_outerOctave_1",
                "EndpointID": "fc3c5b47a330a68e7b0ff494f1fde3926b429158a1846197d31b11b0aae083cd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:29",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.41/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "6f3533a85093ddde99cac38201ab379bbba2948f08da50a4a173be982cea7c2a": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800040_1",
                "EndpointID": "9615b87b9cea2f94ba46b0005d4b73c31cf358446cf3bf3ec94894a25a12241a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:0e",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.14/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7100bd89110864bc254023ffb53bab12883897c42ba7cd5adb29a8b894150f20": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800033_1",
                "EndpointID": "2bb75565256cb335c1f076e2e4ef4acc5623e0d0bdf4aa1b7c0514fa4eb04f51",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:09",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.9/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "801f8d9ddeebf4c1e5f692797cdd65650cd09e05b23eab4e7886cc183c79b6c3": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400016_1",
                "EndpointID": "e0b0f28260a5a03c79b7f41f1bf8db9640848c6d0aed35d6fdd53cba03d61366",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:0b",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.11/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "809d22241a480f9192f29edc5d03e79db33043cc9bfa763639e67e8cfdd80f0e": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400015_1",
                "EndpointID": "638e6b1cddd1fe78a11de8622ab42ca8ee967303330277e2187261b426aa2f8b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:1e",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.30/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "86995a099365f63f6112c25e3e784f6610ae278702c812b61370e186ca53e2ad": {
                "Name": "dev_s3storage_1",
                "EndpointID": "e4c8299d772eaa6a57a63bd351585ec5785c09f6df2e785730ae41d4ff3a25f2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:19",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.25/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8b8e754c99ff6226e8ccd03a150173dfb06e6309c9774c263ae006d9f53f52aa": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800022_1",
                "EndpointID": "dbd31d8e3150192e87b8917927d07729e0603f5288dcc9f296650f34f06c37ee",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:1c",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.28/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8cf73e2e2503e52bfcafbc1c9322b994127df20c359ca624be644210abd57dbc": {
                "Name": "dev_tileserver_1",
                "EndpointID": "77374f4cde143d455c0f062e673008c8b41fe4b2977392c9982bc0052217c6c3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8e05504ce48d890fa9359938c533b4495814e67f36c8c5b24a736812a5eb0e2f": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400028_1",
                "EndpointID": "9d26d053da0d0945d3ff707bccba3cbb12fb81f295678c3604ad60eb9aa9ef2c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:1f",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.31/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "968b41556187c66cb31e623b063d3acf594eb6abac0aa5444bc85d017a807ba6": {
                "Name": "dev_outerWeb_1",
                "EndpointID": "1959455650da340d1d59f8d6011b88657371d7e7e2db02db69462b6747835f97",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:28",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.40/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9a12736c89c8005b32ff9f11283dfbd666ad201fbd9a45bb1c5ad0f20b5f52eb": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400011_1",
                "EndpointID": "c23c6ac83769cf06ccc856a47aa0859a9da3f942e7e792384842dde54564e463",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:25",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.37/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9d12ef78d15fec44b4fa42878c4268d1ec4ac21db4f694bc02d208acd1b561df": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400012_1",
                "EndpointID": "e0f1c3f68bdfa4e7205b6ea8acad4ec791393139e54fc823b9cc7e079c2e419a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b2958a80d70e47692c9ac69314b4fd69acc3e18760f644dceb8142d23d046b3a": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800007_1",
                "EndpointID": "c285a1c6e276ff364bbb72d60ba94eea247aa524d6e9477de8fb92f60b4a8f83",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:0c",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.12/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b7f4d47981571d0970c1db4dc065a1c93186287b50938b1f1e5acc972678735b": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400014_1",
                "EndpointID": "8625c39b48c0000b79c13b1d1f21ba07ce16b8813cf786a94ceedc8a84cda55d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c08e59d978c478cd6bb8c30b1ff0dc51b10ac10fc616e6fc24d3600391d4b3da": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400020_1",
                "EndpointID": "1b629f69d2364e39375cd4cb4e42bd5e34332e468b04169a7fcaa167d58f3f19",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:24",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.36/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c84a447df4e5b632e042e567033d243017b6f0ba58f97be1222110d50b1019b3": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400023_1",
                "EndpointID": "642b31dd4818063828c9889237416aa7b297391fe557530e11959c971278d0dd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:26",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.38/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ca15d4fee3f45b8d8a7552aaa519563d2b1b8ea13c51c0c0d1cd94765cf94512": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400009_1",
                "EndpointID": "8a62973b92ad70a6aad08b717c1ff26fd781cd97e341d2d8ed753a2d2294d00e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:11",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.17/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "cb4fd70cdb8dac59bff2c0257224dc1d261df2770b50221132e5a23997afd1d6": {
                "Name": "dev_maineternaldb_1",
                "EndpointID": "d4cec9ce4110dd188bf7c958b89433d40d436b46f212fbdf35c0dcbcdf0831b9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:08",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.8/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e4d60f497831a9c38ebf96a2d48aed8bfb26928a2ed76ba2b8e77139c4b832bc": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-22800004_1",
                "EndpointID": "61a18f0b561336186ca3bf01a8b3439396f9c76e3ba76b28c7ec355441be2dd9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:21",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.33/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e79451e6ad59896d21fcd88301ce099917ef96ea3d32a3060cb79978b6421fcf": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-19400036_1",
                "EndpointID": "e3303c42d1b0ebac104762b989229773501b3a8e5b5c7059c765543e3031e8b6",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:1a",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.26/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ead3cffd714f12160dde8e35bae0222b521d6264338267edf9c00bbb11b0ebde": {
                "Name": "dev_mainOctave_1",
                "EndpointID": "e5f4c078e4b1ed13fd52eb5740f38c59760388a8bed6b01549841a649db6fb94",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:2a",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.42/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ec9aeb9218cef0b8176e3713258812dfcfba5baa691b9639e50fe965b5681cea": {
                "Name": "dev_outerq_1",
                "EndpointID": "69756ebf2b6a1bdceff4f37fe1dad22859983f417bdbe8e4ab82bd23668500fc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:13",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.19/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f2b86f1ae769358a413c94d6bc7c129e50cdf2a6afe12d86be1e5b85fce6cad7": {
                "Name": "dev_web2_1",
                "EndpointID": "0efa83f1aaef42831b312582fbd7ac25c202f7650d237ea30c72de01eaffd1a8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:27",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.39/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f3ed055ec5f6a6bf6ab73b6db24a495e531e2078694ad523723880e9ae7627e7": {
                "Name": "dev_emulator-77700000_1",
                "EndpointID": "a3ecfc5de45ba1bc0dd491f6dc4052034b077d0e3f717f182751b2a29e42e850",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:1d",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.29/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fca06c99c6f6140161a007bab98e885f468a40a21318f9b7be2fdec322645db9": {
                "Name": "dev_maincouchdb_1",
                "EndpointID": "45b118cabc4a5ca41a968f3d382045a9a1b62939f0a871cedb64a3f0068a0aec",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:1b",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.27/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

```
sudo docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "3e046a2f4038ab5cf2c2989c7c7adb2bb2f75cd75fef18d133cc7d6952b8fa72",
        "Created": "2020-02-14T13:25:50.571033335+03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

```
sudo docker info

Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 117
 Server Version: 19.03.5-ce
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: d50db0a42053864a270f648048f9a8b4f24eced3.m
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.5.2-1-MANJARO
 Operating System: Manjaro Linux
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 31.33GiB
 Name: gemini-f5
 ID: EXYX:H5OE:U74F:HHTF:6P4M:B7HJ:YEXR:S34A:PPXJ:W56Z:BI3D:2DXI
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  dockerregistry.smart-dn.ru:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: What is the application inside your containers like ? Try going to /var/lib/docker/overlay/ and doing   ls | xargs -I {} du -shx {}. Go into the largest directory and then the associated diff directory. Run the command again and you will find what is causing that error. What does docker system df gives you ? What is  occupying most space ? give me the output of "docker system df "

Comment: So the `FIlesystem is not responding` error is being produced by Docker, at the time these 43 containers are being started? Do those containers then fail to load? And, once the first filesystem error occurs, all subsequent containers have the same issue? or is it intermittent?

Comment: So the FIlesystem is not responding error is being produced by Docker, at the time these 43 containers are being started? - Yes

Do those containers then fail to load? - Not every time

A lot of filesystem errors occurs at startup in one time.

Comment: Too much rows from du how to find largest? @ShashankPai

Comment: 1st one is your largest .

Comment: First is 5.9M but I see 69M and 18M below.

Comment: du -shc /var/lib/docker/overlay/*/diff | sort -n -r | head -n 20

Comment: what is the disk space on your local system ? Try docker system prune -a and try again .

Comment: disk space is ok. 100gb free @ShashankPai

Comment: Could you provide `docker info`, please? Any warnings there?

Comment: updated with docker info. No warnings there. Warnings goes from manjaro  @JanGaraj

Comment: Everything looks fine from the docker perspective. Could you please check the filesystem consistency of the mounted device at /var/lib/docker for any possible corruptions. Use fsck for that and post the result.  Caution: Check that filesystem is not busy. Safer way is to umount it first then run fsck.

Answer (score 0):

hi we have same problems sometimes when using nfs share volumes,sometimes on filesystem,all depend on how many volumes you have.

Simple answer is docker is not build to start up lots of containers.

Our production server when we make once per mont maintance (rebooting) starting 100 containers somtimes even 1 hour. producing not only filesystem (IO read/write) errors.

Try to find a way to block these

> pushed as notifications in my manjaro KDE

containers will eventualy start up
we didnt find any solution

our stable workaround was rancher.com and another servers. Rancher helped in way of self distributing containers to server with low resource usage.

Comment: Do you want to say no need to pay attention to these errors? Containers will run ok eventually?

Comment: i cant say that without proper info,like logging and testing. We started monitoring this situations,at the end we find out that without properly mounted filesystem docker container wont start,also depending containers wait for services depending on,and so on.Eventualy it worked all itself and fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has s.th. to do with Python's `request` library like described in [docker-compose restart connection pool full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638699/docker-compose-restart-connection-pool-full). I suggest to try the solution and search for the setting `DEFAULT_POOLSIZE` and set it to a higher value.

On my mac this parameter can be found in /usr/local/homebrew/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py.

This file may of course be overwritten as soon as you update that library however I did not found another way to set this parameter.