# App Engine Python 3 Deferred Generating "Connection pool is full" Warnings

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine

I recently ported my Python 2 App Engine project to Python 3, accessing legacy bundled services.  After a couple of months of work, everything seems to be working.

Except, when I run a batch job via `deferred.defer`, the logs show numerous identical warning messages:

> Connection pool is full, discarding connection: appengine.googleapis.internal. Connection pool size: 10

I've seen some discussion about urllib and requests in relation to this message, but this batch routine is not making any external url requests.  It's just reading and writing to the ndb datastore.

Frankly, I don't know what a connection pool is, I never had to deal with one before, and deferred is supposed to work identically in Python 3.

Does anyone know what this means, what the consequences are, and what I should do about it?  The process appears to run to completion.

Comment: Have you tried this [approach](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/253#issuecomment-686283902)? Also have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66671026/18265702).

Comment: It might be possible to use the approach you mention (although we are not using requests), but I wouldn't want to increase the pool without understanding implications.  Moreover, we aren't consciously doing anything related: we read in a batch of entities in a single ndb call, make in-memory changes, write them out in a single ndb call, then call deferred with the cursor to handle the next batch.  I don't understand what is happening that connections would be used in the first place.  I had seen the Stackoverflow link, and the main takeaway is that the warnings don't matter, but still...